# Dumping route changes from openbgpd

Tags: freebsd, bgp

I have an openbgpd installation running on FreeBSD. I want to capture the routes whenever there is a change. Is there any way of getting this from the logs, or writing a hook to listen for such events?

Comment: Do the dump or log updates configuration options not do what you want ?

Comment: @Iain - Yes, these seem to be what I am looking for. Thanks.

Comment: For reference. I've never run a freebsd system in my life. All I did was go and read the documentation for you. You really should learn to do that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `dump` and `log updates` configuration options that may do what you want.